# Question about how they get forms in proof of "The square of any odd int has the form 8m+1 for some int m"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, square-numbers, parity

[image]

Can someone tell me how they determine that it can be written in those particular forms?

Comment: Did you even read your question? The quotient-remainder algorithm (I call it the division algorithm) says we can write it in this form.

Comment: Have you looked up the quotient-remainder theorem? This is, as the author says, a direct consequence of that theorem. Informally, in this case it’s just saying that when you divide $n$ by $4$, the remainder must be $0,1,2$, or $3$.

Comment: Ohh. Alright, I see it now. Thanks Brian. Perhaps I've been at this a bit too long... Should have noticed that after staring at it so long. :/

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for any integer $x$, the remainder of $x$ when divided by $4$ has to be $0,1,2$ or $3$. Let $r$ be this remainder. Since $x-r$ must be divisible by $4$, we can let $\frac{x-r}{4} = q$ for some integer $q$. Thus:

$$
\begin{align*}
x & = 4(\frac{x-r+r}{4})\\
& = 4(\frac{x-r}{4} + \frac{r}{4})\\
& = 4q + r
\end{align*}
$$

Since $r$ is $0,1,2$ or $3$, then $x$ has to be of the form $4q$,$4q+1$,$4q+2$ or $4q+3$